# How to integrate Disqus to Facebook Connect-enabled site (python Tornado app)

Tags: python, tornado, disqus

I succesfully use Facebook auth for my Tornado-based site using FacebookMixin. I also have Facebook Connect auth enabled for my Disqus, which placed in page using javascript widget. When user already logged in using FB to my site, they still have to log to FB again when they want to comment using Disqus.

How Discus FB Connect suppose to works? I assumed i got seamless FB auth between those two (FacebookMixin/Disqus)

Comment: Did you ever found out how to do a seamless integration? i'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

how did you integrate disqus into your site? are you using their [api](http://wiki.disqus.net/API) in your backend?

If I understand disqus correctly then you would need to post to their service usign the data of the authenticated users, else (if they use the javascript widget) they would need to establish a fb connect session with disqus which might be a confusing experience.

Comment: i use javascript widget. indeed confusing thus my question. i assume when tornado facebookmixin successfully authenticated the user, it set cookies and disqus js know those cookies are exists so no need to fbconnect-ing. am i confusing facebookmixin with fb connect?